# How to avoid SWIG's "Deprecated command line option: -modern. This option is now always on."

Tags: python, c++, swig

Since I'm running an updated system, my build logs (in this case, GNU Radio) are cluttered with

```
Deprecated command line option: -modern. This option is now always on.
```

I've boiled that down to SWIG as culprit. However (as usual), the SWIG documentation and changelogs don't specify when that was added, so that I'm having a hard time disabling the `-command` argument depending on the used SWIG version.

Since which SWIG version is that option always on?

Answer (score 2):

Intense blaming on the humongous [swig/Source/Modules/Python.cxx](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Source/Modules/python.cxx) led to the realization that this happened in git commit e4fceee12; `git describe e4fceee12` yields rel-3.0.12-1146-ge4fceee12, i.e. SWIG release 3.0.12.

I've been able to disable it using

```
    set(modern_keyword "-modern")
    if("${SWIG_VERSION}" VERSION_GREATER "3.0.12")
      set(modern_keyword "")
    endif()
    set(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS … ${modern_keyword} …)
```

in my CMake infrastructure.

Comment: That's *after* 3.0.12, so you need to adjust your condition, since 3.0.13 would be the first release with it.

Comment: @o11c true, typo in my CMake file – fixed, thanks! (there's no 3.0.13, to my knowledge; only 4.0.0)